# Trouble posting XML to Node Highrise API

Tags: angularjs, xml, node.js, coffeescript, highrise

I am trying to make a post request to [Highrise](https://highrisehq.com/) API using the npm package `node-highrise-api`.  It takes XML and I have been getting a response from the API but unsuccessfully passing data.  Here's my code:

```
  studentNote = "<note><body>hello</body><subject-id type=\"integer\">267869152</subject-id><subject-type>Status Change</subject-type></note>"

    rp.post "https://token:a@name.highrisehq.com/people/id/notes.xml", studentNote
      .then (response) ->
        highriseData = xml2js.parseStringAsync response, {trim: true}
        console.log highriseData
      .catch (err) ->
        console.log 'this err'
        console.log err
        null
```

rp is request-promise, an npm package that enables promises with the request npm package.

The response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <author-id type="integer">1232986</author-id>
  <collection-id type="integer" nil="true"></collection-id>
  <collection-type nil="true"></collection-type>
  <created-at type="datetime">2016-09-22T20:52:16Z</created-at>
  <group-id type="integer" nil="true"></group-id>
  <id type="integer">381833222</id>
  <owner-id type="integer" nil="true"></owner-id>
  <subject-id type="integer">267869152</subject-id>
  <subject-type>Party</subject-type>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2016-09-22T20:52:16Z</updated-at>
  <visible-to>Everyone</visible-to>
  <body nil="true"></body>
  <subject-name>Parentof Student</subject-name>
</note>
```

If you look at the body, subject id, and subject type tags, the data I passed is not being sent back in the response.

Does anyone have any suggestions for dealing with an XML API?

Thanks in advance